# Users adding views

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ipad

I have created a main page (myAppViewController) and a add page rect button I have also created a page template (TemplateAViewController) all set up in Interface builder. 
I would like users to be able to add as many templates themselves and then page through them.

I am not sure where to start. I can create views programmatic like so

```
-(IBAction)createnewpage : (id) sender { 
    myAppViewController  *viewcontroller = [[myAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TemplateAViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
   [[self view] addSubview:viewcontroller.view]; 
}
```

I then want to be able to navigate through these views- I guess I need to create a navigation controller to do this ?

Btw this is for iPad ONLY

Answer (score 0):

By navigation if you mean access the views programmatically, just do :

```
for (UIView *view in [self view].subviews) {
...
}
```

Edit:

Looking at your code, it seems that you were adding all views as subviews to a view of a fixed UIViewController `[[self view] addSubview:customView]`

Based on that, you can access each subview of your view controller from the mentioned `for loop`.
I hope I am clear now

Comment: I had worked out switching views another way - I dont quite understand what you are suggesting ? can you explain a little more - I want to step through all views that have been dynamically created (via an add page button)

Comment: http://vimeo.com/8930397  I used this tutorial to learn how to switch views however i need to be able to step through views - but before that I need to be able to let users add views

Comment: added some further description to it. So essentially I am doing something like "for each subview of [self view] do the following"